# Cant get rid of left padding

Tags: html, css

The image is going off to the right of the div, I am trying to align it to the left.

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Gyhc.png) you can see there is not background on the image

```css
.title {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  background: transparent url(https://lorempixel.com/200/200) no-repeat top left;
}
```

```html
<div class="title"></div>
```

Here it shows the sizing of the div, this is aligned to the left yet the image itself which has no excess background, it is just the text in the image

[image]

There may be unnecessary properties in CSS, this is just to show what i have tried

Comment: try removing position:abosolute

Comment: If you want to override a rule or be sure to override:  padding: 0px !important;

Comment: background:transparent url(title.png) no-repeat 0% 15%;

Comment: I've changed your picture URL to a random image for us to see what happens... But everything seems fine. Either show us the original image, or add more code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: unfortunately removing absolute did not work, nor did overriding the padding and/or margin with  padding: 0px !important; , likewise with no repeat 0% 15%.

Comment: Also, padding has nothing to do with background, unless the appropriate background-clip is set.

Comment: @Salketer Ive added the original title.png image to my question.

Comment: What are you calling background in your image? If you are saying the text should be on the edge of the picture, you are wrong, there is 703 pixels wide, not 453... it is normal it is truncated.

Answer (score 0):

I took an image from google just for the test and its aligned to the left.

Maybe the issue in other selector.

By removing `position:absolute;` image will positioned on top.

```css
.title {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
  top: 300px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  background: transparent url(https://lorempixel.com/200/200) no-repeat top left;
}
```

```html
<div class="title"></div>
```

Comment: It does seem to work with other images but i dont see how the issue could be with another selector, if it works for on image. It would indicate that it was something wrong with the image however the image has its background removed, i will add an image to my question to show this.

Comment: @liam My suggestion is to crop the image and don't use workaround solution in css, it will reduce image size and solve your issue

Comment: The image is cropped, see edited question. I have added the original image which is in my main folder